# CORS not working across AWS API Gateway, S3 and browsers?

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, cors

I have a setup where a static file in S3 submits a POST request to API Gateway, but I really struggle getting the CORS setup correctly.

In my last attempts I have even hard coded the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be the s3 domain but to no avail.

In postman I see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin correctly returned as expected, but when requesting data from S3 it is denied in chrome and safari. I tried having a wildcard for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as well, but same effect.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

**edit**
I have enabled CORS in API Gateway as well, I have attached screenshots of those. Thanks for pointing this out in the responses!

[image: OPTIONS header values]

[image: POST overview]

[image: POST method with CORS]

[image: OPTIONS method with CORS]

[image]

[image: Safari error message]

Comment: Just checking... Did you [Enable CORS for an API Gateway Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)?

Comment: Also... did you deploy the API after enabling CORS? I have forgotten to deploy after doing this several times.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @JohnRotenstein and ranmam, I have updated the post. I did a re-deploy just to make sure as well - I have been caught there too..

Answer (score 2):

After some serious head scratching I found my problem to be that I was using a combination of resource proxying together with the CORS OPTIONS resource that AWS automatically adds. With resource proxying to my lambda function I couldn't specify the origin headers, and I assumed it would be added anyway because of the 'Enable CORS' step I performed. I stopped using resource proxying and wrote out the mappings manually and the problem went away (now I could specify the header value myself in the integration mapping).